# DnD Next (Final Playtest) Finesse + Ability Modifier Damage

Tags: damage, attack, dnd-next-playtest

The the How to play document says

> Weapon Attacks. If you’re attacking with a melee weapon, apply your Strength 
>       modifier to the damage, and if you’re attacking with a ranged weapon, apply 
>       your Dexterity modifier.
>
> Certain weapons and special abilities allow you to apply a different modifier. 
>       For example, a finesse weapon is a melee weapon that lets you attack with your 
>       Dexterity modifier instead of your Strength modifier.

I noticed that it specifically does not say anything about damage modifier when using finesse. only attack.  And in 3.5 it was spelled out that finesse replaces STR with DEX for attack bonus, but not for the damage bonus on the attack.

But I could not find any more specific reference with regard to D&D Next. Therefore:

Does an attack with a finesse weapon apply the DEX or the STR modifier as bonus damage? Assuming 12 STR, 16 DEX, and a 1d6 finesse weapon: Is the damage 1d6+1 or 1d6+3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1d6+3**

> *Finesse.* When making an attack with a finesse
>   weapon, you can use your choice of your Strength or Dexterity modifier with your attack and damage rolls. - Equipment Rules, P. 4

Any attack made with a weapon that has the finesse keyword lets you use either **STR** for attack *and* damage modifiers or **DEX** for attack *and* damage modifiers.

Comment: Since much was made of the location of the ambiguous rule, could you tell us where the clear ruling was found?

Comment: Equipment packet meant the pdf labeled equipment, have edited it to say equipment rules and added the page number where the quote can be found.